# Path of C++ Custom Action DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I have created a C++ Custom Action DLL. I have an msi that calld from the DLL but the DLL is not included in the MSI, It is in the same location as it.

I use the following to get the location of the MSI:

```
TCHAR* szValueBuf = NULL;
DWORD cchValueBuf = 0;
UINT uiStat =  MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("OriginalDatabase"), TEXT(""), &cchValueBuf);

if (ERROR_MORE_DATA == uiStat)
{
    ++cchValueBuf; 
    szValueBuf = new TCHAR[cchValueBuf];
    if (szValueBuf)
    {
        uiStat = MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("OriginalDatabase"), szValueBuf, &cchValueBuf);
    }
}
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != uiStat)
{
    if (szValueBuf != NULL) 
        delete[] szValueBuf;
    return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
}
```

This works great and gets me the full path, However the path has the name of the MSI at the end and I need to remove this to put in the name of my DLL or is there another way?

I have tried:

```
std::string s = "NPath";

int pos = s.find_last_of("\\");
s.erase(0, pos + 1);
s.erase(s.length() - 4, 4);
s.append("product.ini");
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out:

```
 char * pch;
 pch = strstr (szValueBuf,"ServerSetup.msi");
 strncpy (pch,"product.ini",15);
 puts (szValueBuf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use C or C++ string functions to remove all characters back to the last slash or back-slash. Then append your DLL name.

If you wish to get fancier you could use the C++ library Boost::Filesystem.

Comment: Hi, i've edited my question above, can you help any more please?